# Удалить текст, не соответствующий регулярному выражению

Tags: регулярные-выражения, php

Приветствую., как можно удалить текст, который не соответствует регулярному выражению?

```
$string = "text 127.0.0.1:80 text text";
if(preg_match('/[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\:[0-9]{1,5}/', $string)) {

}
```

Айпи и порт нужно оставить, остальное — удалить.

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: [preg_replace()][1]?

   [1]:http://us3.php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-replace.php

Answer (score 1):

Для удаления текста не соответствующего регулярному выражению воспользуйтесь универсальным шаблоном

```
preg_replace( "/(?:(regex)|.)/s", "$1", $text);
```